# Exchanges in Distance Vector routing

Tags: routes, hyperlink, router

A network of 4 routers A, B, C and D are arranged as below. All use distance vector routing.

`A----B----C----D`

Value of infinity is 8.

Initially router A was down all routers adjusted their routing tables accordingly. Now, it comes back up. How many exchanges are needed for router A table to stabilize. Assume all routers exchange messages at the same instant.

The following solution was given:

```
Start        inf     inf    inf
1 Exchange    1      inf    inf
2 Exchange    1       2     inf
3 Exchange    1       3      3
4 Exchange    1       3      3
```

Answer = 4

**But what I think is B can share its whole routing table to A because it has the hop counts to C and D as well. So, this can be done in 1 exchange only.**

Need clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, B can send its table to A, but all the other nodes need to get the new distance to A.

I'd think it goes something like:

1) B sends A table and new B->A = 1 (< inf)

2) B sends C (B->A = 1), so new C->A = 2 (< inf)

3) C sends D (C->A = 2), so new D->A = 3 (< inf)

4) D sends C (D->A = 3), but C->A = 2 < 4 = D->A + 1, so C->A stays 2

The table provided looks wrong, I think it should be: (assuming my assumption about the column meanings are correct)

```
             B->A    C->A   D->A
Start        inf     inf    inf
1 Exchange    1      inf    inf
2 Exchange    1       2     inf
3 Exchange    1       2      3
4 Exchange    1       2      3
```